# Correct use of CSS

Tags: css, html

I have tried to format my page with CSS without too much luck so far.

I need to have the big image centered (horizontally) and just a bit displaced from the top.
Then I need to put some text on top of it , and also a small image (on top of the big image as well).

I am trying to do this using **div** but every time something slips me.
Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Post what you have

Comment: You could even provide a little diagram. I'm not sure if you mean small image "on top" like above the big image so both are visible, or if you mean op top like laid over the top of the larger image so part of the large image is covered.

Comment: @bwawok : I did not post any code because I have made several unfortunate attempts..
@Jage : sorry, I was not clear. I mean that a part of the large image will be covered as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could post a link it would be nice...

```
<div style="background:transparent url(bigimage.jpg) no-repeat center center;width:500;min-height:500;">
<p>my text</p>
<img alt="" src="smallimage.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to pay a visit to www.w3schools.com on the css reference in the right, you can test with css code and view the result of each tag.